# Как сохранить точную позицию аккорда над словом в Textview?

Tags: java, android, textview, музыка

**Контекст:**

мобильное приложение (Android) с песнями и аккордами для пения под гитару.

**Задача:**

Необходимо, чтобы в тексте песни сверху над словами были указаны аккорды. Аккорды должны быть выделены жирным. При этом аккорды должны располагаться над теми частями текста, где необходим переход именно на этот аккорд - такая задача реализована путём расставления пробелов между аккордами над текстом самой песни.

В качестве исходных данных нам даны тексты песен (txt), где с помощью пробелов сдвинуты аккорды на нужные места.

Пример:

[image]

Как бы вы решили эту задачу?

UPD1: Пробовал забирать весь текст из файла в строку, добавлять теги переноса строк, заменять пробелы на    и с помощью Html.fromHtml(data) переводить всё в HTML, но отчего-то аккорды всё равно немного съезжают (выделил там, где съехало).

```
data = data.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "<br>");
data = data.replace(" ", "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(data));
```

[image]

UPD2: Проанализировав предложенные и дополнительные варианты (например, использовать Ionic и в CSS верстать аккорды над нужными словами), пришёл к выводу, что 90% потребностей будут перекрыты использованием обычного ImageView с картинкой текста и аккордов.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как бы вы решили эту задачу?

Ну, если так ставить вопрос, то я при наличии времени и избытка перфекционизма реализовал бы эту часть на OpenGL. Правда в таком случае я бы не ограничился простым выведением текста, но и добавил бы всякие эффекты.

А если прибегнуть к методу, который будет ближе к реальности, то вам нужно что то типа:

```
Paint paint = new Paint(); 
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL); 
canvas.drawPaint(paint); 

paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
paint.setTextSize(20); 
canvas.drawText("Some Text", 10, 25, paint);
```

Comment: Интересный вариант:)
А если ближе к реальности, то чтобы вы посоветовали, чтобы реализовать то, что мне нужно?

Comment: @dennydenny добавил в ответ другой вариант :)

Answer (score 0):

Делаешь кастомную ViewGroup с двумя TextView. Одна для аккорда (может быть скрыта, всегда расположена по центра по горизонтали, свой стиль, и т.д.), вторая - для слова. Каждая строчка песни - горизонтальный LinearLayout, в который программно подсовываются эти самые ViewGroup`ы.